Necessary and sufficient condition to at least two cubic polynomial roots have absolute value lower than 1
I have a cubic polynomial $$\lambda^3+a_2 \lambda^2+a_1 \lambda + a_0$$ I need that at least two of its roots have absolute value lower than 1. Is there any theorem that provides necessary and sufficient conditions for this?
Here we have a necessary and sufficient condition to all roots have absolute value lower than 1. But I need that at least two of them have this property.
I would like any help.

$(\lambda-r)(\lambda^2-(s^2+t^2))=0;\space r,s,t\in\mathbb R$

Let's call your polynomial $f(\lambda)$, and let $C$ be the positively oriented unit circle.  Assuming none of the roots are on $C$, the number of roots (counted by multiplicity) inside the unit circle is the winding number of $f(C)$ around $0$, which is
$$ \frac{1}{2\pi i} \oint_C \frac{f'(z)}{f(z)} \; dz $$
So you want that to be $2$ or $3$.

In the book titled, "Periodicities in Nonlinear Difference Equations", E. A. Grove and G. Ladas (2005, CRC Press) give many important results for the stability of polynomials that arise in discrete-time linear systems.
Result 1: Consider the second-order polynomial equation
$$
\lambda^2 + a_1 \lambda + a_0 = 0 \ \ \  \ (1)
$$
where $a_0$ and $a_1$ are real numbers. Then a necessary and sufficient condition for both roots of the quadratic equation (1) to lie inside the open unit disc $|\lambda| < 1$ is
$$
|a_1| < a_0 + 1 < 2
$$
Result 2: Consider the third-order polynomial equation
$$
\lambda^3 + a_2 \lambda^2 + a_1 \lambda + a_0 = 0 \ \ \  \ (2)
$$
where $a_0, a_1$ and $a_2$ are real numbers. Then a necessary and sufficient condition for all the roots of the cubic equation (2) to lie inside the open unit disc $|\lambda| < 1$ is
$$
|a_2 + a_0| < 1 + a_1, \ |a_2 - 3 a_0| < 3 - a_1, \ a_0^2 + a_1 - a_0 a_2 < 1
$$
[E. A. Grove and G. Ladas have also given a necessary and sufficient condition for the discrete-time stability of a fourth order polynomial equation, which can be read in their book published by CRC Press. Proof is not given in their work, and they have stated it in the Preliminaries.]
